# Checking / Unckecking Checkbox based on Input Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a simple form that has a checkbox that is checked by default.
I also have a text input field. If I enter text in the input field I want the checkbox to be unchecked.

However if I then delete the text in the text input I want the checkbox to be checked again.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='t1' checked>
<input type="text" name="t2">
```

Any idea how I can do that using JQUERY ?

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[name="t2"]').keyup(function () {
    $('input[name="t1"]').prop("checked", $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/57jHx/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prop()` method

```
$('input[name="t2"]').keyup(function(){
   var input=$('input[name="t1"]');
   if($(this).val().trim()==="")
     input.prop("checked",true);
   else
     input.prop("checked",false);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/X6wJM/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Bind keyup function on your text input that will set prop('checked', true|false) on your checkbox depending on if current text input value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#points').keyup(function () {
    console.log($(this).val())
    if($(this).val()==""){
    $('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false); // Checks it        
    }else{
    $('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', true); // Unchecks it
    }
});
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DMH5/129/)**

Comment: I didn't downvote, but why did you leave the console.log in your example and why use an old version of jQuery in your fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `oninput` to detect when the textbox field value changes:

```
$('input[name=t2]').on('input propertychange',function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length > 0) {
        $('input[name=t1]').prop('checked',false);
    } else {
        $('input[name=t1]').prop('checked',true);
    }
});
```

Note: The `propertychange` is used here for the sack of compatibility with old IE versions that does not support `oninput`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Y7y/)